# When textInput focused, first touch on flatList doesn't work, however the second works

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

When I type something into TextInput, then I touch one of FlatList items first time. It should `console.log('item press')`, but it not. Only the second touch It consoles. Does someone know the reason?

This is my code.

```js
<TextInput
    placeholder='test'
    value={this.state.inputText}
    onChangeText={(inputText) => this.setState({inputText})}
    style={{
        marginBottom: 20, 
        fontSize: 17, 
        width: 300, 
        textAlign: 'center''
    }}
/>
<FlatList
    data={[{key: 'item 1'}, {key: 'item 2'}]}
    renderItem={({item}) =>
        <TouchableHighlight 
            onPress={() => console.log('item press')}
            underlayColor='#dddddd'
        >
            <View style={{height: 40}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 16, textAlign: 'center'}}>{item.key}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    }
/>
```

Comment: react-native version: 0.46.1, I have test 0.47, same problem

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should use the `FlatList` with `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}` prop and handle your keyboard close in another function by `Keyboard.Dissmiss()`. your `FlatList` will be like this:

```
       <FlatList
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}
          data={[{key: 'item 1'}, {key: 'item 2'}]}
          renderItem={({item}) =>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log('item press')}
                                underlayColor='#dddddd'>
              <View style={{height: 40}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 16, textAlign: 'center'}}>{item.key}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          }
        />
```

You can use the `Keyboard.dismiss()` function in the `onPress` prop after  in the `console.log('item press')` command in `TouchableHighlight` component.

Comment: THX, this is perfect!

Comment: Happy to help you.

Comment: Official documentation says that `FlatList` does not have `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` property, can see only inside the source code...

Comment: I can't scroll with this approach

Comment: @SebaKZ Can u explain a little bit more about your problem.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I can't scroll because there wasn't scroll, given the items fit in the screen. But I didn't realize because the keyboard was shown and there was some items I could't see. So I'm using KeyboardAwareView to solve that.

Comment: Didn't need Keyboard.dismiss() after using keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'} for the Flatlist

Comment: It's not working in my case. I tried `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` with all values but none of working. Not firing `TouchableHighlight` onPress method.

Comment: Give this guy a medal!